# Digital Rights Management(DRM) options for Microsoft word document using C#

Tags: c#, drm, word-addins

I am trying to make my own application for Microsoft Office Word DRM options.
like: Read only, Print, Encrypted, Watermark.

Details:
I made MS Word add-in for DRM options.
I will handle the printing and readonly permission by using **Application_DocumentBeforePrint** and **Application_DocumentOpen**.
But,
I want help for these one.
My file is in encrypted format. So, when I was trying to open that file (On double click), it gives an error for **content is not proper**.
So, I want to decrypt file on click and then open.
At a time of close or Exit file will encrypted again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that by the time Word opens your document it is already invalid. To Word it is just a bunch of invalid bytes, which in your case, is the encrypted document.

You could create a new file extension and register that type with a new shell application (that your write) that performs the decryption and uses Word to open the document. Handling the save (and encryption) would be triggered by your AddIn.